# Create composite field in facet term script

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Elasticsearch in Ruby through the Tire gem. I have indexed articles which have tags, who are nested under articles.

I created a facet for the tags like this:

```
facet "tags" do
  terms 'tags.name'
end
```

This gives me the tag name and count in the facet. But I also need the ID of the tag.

So I need to create a composite field in my facet (like `lorem|12`) which I can split later to get both name and ID.

How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
facet 'tags' do
  terms 'tags.name', script: "term + \"|\" + _source.id"
end
```

But this doesn't work as the `_source` is the article and NOT the tag so I can't reach the tag ID like this.

Is it possible to create this type of composite field using a script? How?

Comment: Is there a reason why you couldn't just put the ids in the 'tags' facet and translate back to name in your UI code? Script facets are generally very slow.

Comment: @MattiasNordberg, The main reason is that I don't want to load the Tags from my other DB if I can get all the data I need directly from the Elasticsearch query. But perhaps it is worse to use a facet script than to just load the real Tags from my other DB...

Comment: I don't know nothing about this scripting language but maybe a solution like this: terms 'tags.custom', script: "tags.name+ \"|\" + tags.id"